# How to make a database connection converting mysql to PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to convert all my mysql code into PDO. First thing Im trying to convert to PDO is my database connection. Can somebody help me on the right way?....

Here comes my database connection in mysql:

```
  $host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$password = "root";
$db = "blog";

$bd = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Opps something wrong...");
mysql_select_db($db, $bd) or die("Opps something wrong...");
```

Comment: [Read a nice tutorial on PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: You cannot short-cut on this, you really do have to read the manual and cut aside some time to test out all the options, especially the parts about prepared statements.  You have to bang this stuff into your head.

Comment: @Mihai lorga Thanks, I will take a look on that tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) where you can learn the right way (as well as many other useful things) from someone who had a *real* experience with PDO.

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password, $opt);
```

Unlike all other codes which are useless for handling *connection* errors (as they set exception mode *after* the actual connect) it will

- make PHP throw an exception on connection error
- will not reveal sensitive information to a potential attacker on a live server by echoing an error out.
- provide you with indispensable *stack trace*.
- set the connection encoding in the right place

Unlike your old code it will not die with useless message but it will either

- die with useful error message on-screen
- die with useful error message logged, leaving screen blank
- die with useful error message logged, with conventional error page shown
- not die at all but gracefully handled with designated handler function

... depends on the chosen settings.

Comment: Why don't you add this as a note to the php.net manual page? ;)

Comment: @Your Common Sense Many thanks, your code is working. Now I have to convert all my other code using PDO...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the PHP Manual's [PDO page](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), especially the part on 'Connections and Connection Management': http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

or... use Captain Common Sense's approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Connection with error handling..

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice with a error handling to... Im gonna try your code.

Comment: It has nothing to do with error handling. And it will never raise an error on connect.

Comment: May i know how come it would never possible raise an error on connection?

Comment: @Kaii sure. Just try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
```

**OR**

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

More details [Click here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked [into the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)?

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname', 'youruser', 'yourpassword');
```